# Problem with the type of equation $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{a}$ and vertices?

Tags: functions, derivatives, conic-sections

I am asked to find the type equation $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{a}$ , represents ?
i.e a parabola , or hyperbola or ellipse or circle by squaring twice?

Now , what I have done is like this

$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{a}$$
 $$or,\ x+y-a = -2\sqrt{xy}\ (squaring)$$
 $$or,\ x^2+y^2+a^2-2ax-2ay-2xy = 0\ (squaring\ again)---(1)$$

Now I think this is the equation of a circle , but if I plot the equation $y= x-2 \sqrt{x}+1$ in graph which is obtained by squaring once , I get half of a parabola.

again if I differentiate (1) I get
$$2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}-2a-2a\frac{dy}{dx}-2(x\frac{dy}{dx}+y) = 0$$

Now , if i put $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ ,to maximize the function I get $2x-2y-2a=0$ , 
How the maximum point is the equation of a straight line in 2 dimension? there is no z component here !! can someone clear up a bit ?

Comment: It is (part of) not a circle, circles have no $xy$ term in their equations. (All the other types of conics can have $xy$ terms.) I don't know what machinery you have available, but that $(x-y)^2$ term do look nice.

Comment: I plotted in wolfram

Comment: As far as I know, it's a parabola tangent to both axes.

Answer (score 0):

$ax^2 + bxy + c^2 = 0$ is a parabola if $b^2 = 4ac$ the curve $\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt a$ is part of a parabola because you have $x^2 - 2xy + y^2 + \cdots$ and the discriminant $(-2)^2 - 4*1*1 = 0.$

Comment: How can I find the vertex of this parabola by differentiating ?

Comment: vertex of the parabola is $(a/4, a/4)$. no need to differentiate.

Comment: no , the vertex is (a,0) .. see here ,`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+4%2Bx-2*sqrt%284x%29`